# XML XCode Attribute

Tags: xml, xcode

I am using Google's API to retrieve the current weather.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"condition"]) 
    {    
      NSString* string = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];  
      NSLog(@"The weather is now %@", string);
    }
[self setUIState:ACTIVE_STATE];
}
```

With the above, I am getting 3 conditions. All I need is the current, how do I solve this? Here is the  [xml code](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=singapore).

I am trying to retrieve only the "condition" which is nested inside "current_conditions". Thanks!

Comment: `if([elementName isEqualToString:@"current_conditions"])`

Comment: That's also exactly what I did, but does not solve the problem

Comment: But if you find a better way than mine (below) please, share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BOOL variable to check if you are in the current_conditions. Example:

BOOL retrieveCurrentCondition;

set this in initializer to NO, then

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{   
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"current_conditions"])
    {
        retrieveCurrentCondition= YES;
    }   
}
```

and in `didEndElement` back to NO.

Meanwhile you can implement methods to get whatever you want `if(retrieveCurrentCondition)`